# Update height of div to expanded select element children

Tags: html, css

Maybe there was similar question, but din't find what I exacly looking for. 
I have a div, that contains select element and has an absolute position.
Is there an option to update div's height to select's height when it is expanded? I am looking for css solution.

Here is an basic skeleton:

```
<div id="container" style="position: absolute">
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this before but it's proving hard to track down. Unfortunately, I think the answer is NO....especially crossbrowser. Usually the `select`  need to be replaced with other elements.

Comment: I think I gonna go the "replacement" way. Thank you anyway.